# CLLE SNDRCVF command not allowed

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, control-language

I am trying to compile this piece of CL code using Rational Series but keep getting error.

This is my CL code:

```
         PGM

         DCLF       FILE(LAB4DF)

         SNDRCVF    RCDFMT(RECORD1) /* send, recieve file */
         DOWHILE    (&IN03 = '0')
            SELECT
               WHEN       (&USERINPUT = '1' *OR &USERINPUT = '01') CALLSUBR   OPTION1
               OTHERWISE  DO
                  *IN03      = '1'
               ENDDO
            ENDSELECT
         ENDDO

         SUBR       OPTION1
            DSPLIBL
         ENDSUBR

         ENDPGM
```

And this is my DSPF code

```
 A          R RECORD1
 A                                  1 38'LAB 4'
 A                                  3  3'Please select one of the following-
 A                                       options:'
 A                                  6 11'3.  Maximum Invalid Signon Attempt-
 A                                      s allowed'
 A                                  8 11'5.  Run Instructor''s Insurance Pr-
 A                                      ogram'
 A                                  5 11'2.  Signed on User''s Message Queu-
 A                                      e'
 A                                  1  3'Yathavan Parameshwaran'
 A                                  7 11'4.  Initial number of active jobs -
 A                                      for storage allocation'
 A                                  4 11'1.  Previous sign on by signed on -
 A                                      user'
 A                                 14 11'F3 = Exit'
 A                                 14 31'F21 = Command Line'
 A                                  2 70TIME
 A                                  1 72DATE
 A                                  9 11'Option: '
 A            USERINPUT      2   B  9 19
 A  91                                  DSPATR(RI)
 A  92                                  DSPATR(PC)
 A            MSGTXT1       70   O 11 11
 A            MSGTXT2       70   O 12 11
```

Is there a problem with my CL code or DSPF code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to say what error you were getting. It's always important to put all the information about error messages into your questions.

There are two errors.

- &IN03 is not defined
- Your assignment to *IN03 should be to &IN03, but that's not how you do an assignment in CLP

If you want to be able to press F3, you have to code something like CA03(03) in the "Functions" for the record format.

To assign a variable in CL, code

```
CHGVAR name value
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about the lack of error messages. 

I have been getting mostly the &IN03 error. 

I will try out your suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/cl/sndrcvf.htm), I suspect you need to add `RCDFMT` to your `DCLF` spec like so:

```
     DCLF       FILE(LAB4DF) RCDFMT(RECORD1)

     SNDRCVF    RCDFMT(RECORD1) /* send, recieve file */
```

If you really do only have 1 record format in your display file, then you can also omit the `RCDFMT` from both commands like so:

```
     DCLF       FILE(LAB4DF)

     SNDRCVF    /* send, recieve file */
```

Comment: I tried coding adding another record format to the file. It turns out that as long as you specify the RCDFMT on the SNDRCVF, you don't need to specify the RCDFMT on the DCLF.